# slideshow and responsive menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, responsive

The elements of my HTML menu "Home, News etc..." are bigger than the size of the header.

I have also a problem with my slideshow of images. The images are displayed, but after few seconds, the images disappear.

Here is below all my code.

How can I correct the menu size, and prevent the images in the slideshow from disappearing?

Comment: "Do not hesitate to correct my code". So... where is it?

Comment: I can't put all my code. I will give you soon the link to my test web site